# How could I run a call with extension number by using the telecom class?

Tags: android

I am looking for a help to run call using android telecom class, so it is working fine with phone call number but the issue is when you are calling call center number and asking you to inter a digit to forward the call, how could i implement this in android using telecom class

Comment: Could you add how did you implement that feature?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged